# Why git prepends a `TYPE LENGTH\0` header in object files?

Tags: git

I read the [Git Pro](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) and knew that git prepends an header to object file, which is `TYPE LENGTH\0`, for example:

```
header = "blob #{content.length}\0"
```

But I'm wondering for what purpose git keeps this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that in almost all cases, by the time you have the SHA-1 you know what kind of object you should get: if you start with a branch reference, you should get a commit; if you start with a commit and its `tree` you *must* get a tree; and if you have a tree-ID and read its object, each entry has a `mode` that tells you what the object type should be.

But what if you have a tag reference?  If you read `.git/refs/tags/v2.2.2` and get `da5eda36576c1d45a52f7f60a9e5372aa4e2bb58`, what type do you expect to find for object `da5eda36576c1d45a52f7f60a9e5372aa4e2bb58`?

If `v2.2.2` is a lightweight tag, `da5eda36576c1d45a52f7f60a9e5372aa4e2bb58` will probably be a commit, but it could be a tree or even a blob.  If it's an annotated tag, `da5eda36576c1d45a52f7f60a9e5372aa4e2bb58` will be a tag object.

You could read the target object and guess, but if it's a blob object, it might *look like* a valid annotated tag, commit, or tree.  The only sure way to know is to read the object type.

---

Besides the above, `git cat-file -t` tells you the type, which it can only find from the underlying object.  Of course, if git were designed differently there might not *be* a `git cat-file -t`.  But tags in particular require the type, and once it's there, exposing it via `git cat-file -t` seems reasonable as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've never thought about tags.